# Power BI (DAX) Distinct Count Filtered by Condition (Where Clause)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a customer table with customer transactions. Each customer transaction has `Transaction ID` and each product have `Product Code` and other fields of the customer is `Region Code`, `Country Code`. I can do this with SQL but I need to convert this to `DAX`.

- Question 1

Task 1 Count all Transactions where the  `Product code = '1'`.

- Question 2

Task 2 Count all Transactions where the  `Product code = '2'` and `Region Code = '100'`.

-Question 3

Task 3 Count all Transactions where the  `Product code = '2'` and `Region Code = '100'` AND `Contry Code = '001'`.

Please note this will be measures shown as `KPI/display` card on the dashboard

Thanks so much for your time and help.

**In SQL**,  it will look something like below

**Task 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CountC
WHERE  ProductCode = '1'
```

**Task 2.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CountC
WHERE  ProductCode = '2'
AND RegionCode = '100'
Group by...
```

Answer (score 2):

Formats you could use are:

```
[Measure] :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( MyTable ),
    'Mytable'[column1] = x,
    'Mytable'[column2] = y
)
```

or

```
[Measure] :=
    COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( MyTable, 'Mytable'[column1] = x && 'Mytable'[column2] = y )
)
```

Comment: Great, I have done it I am but getting an error on comparing values of type TEXT with Value of Type INTEGER. Any suggestions for using VALUE or FORMAT functions to convert one of the values?

Comment: What does your expression look like and what is the datatype of the columns you use?

Comment: Data Type Integer::   [Measure] :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( CustomerID),
    'Customer'[ProductCode] = 100,
    'Customer'[CountryCode] = 001
)

Comment: What datatypes are [ProductCode] and [CountryCode]? If they are text, then you should use double quotes. Like: `'Customer'[ProductCode] = "100"`

Comment: Data type is the integer, I have added 'Customer'[ProductCode] = "100" but now I am getting blank display card/